# Countif and countifs on fairly large dataset - how can I improve?

Tags: vba, countif

Good day - thanks in advance for any help.

Working with a moderately sized dataset (currently about 80,000 records, but it will grow over the next few months) and need to do a countif (to show how many instances of a record have been recorded) and a countifs (to show how many instances of each record have a certain value from another sheet).

Right now, I'm doing it with COUNTIF in one column, and COUNTIFS in another ... and it takes quite a while to finish.

Do any of you have any recommendations that I can try, which will accomplish those objectives?

To reiterate 
 - I have a list of 80,000 strings which have been rated as GOOD or BAD
 - I am making a unique list of those strings with a counter for both TOTAL # of Instances (countif) and TOTAl # of BAD ratings.

Thank you so much for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel's buit-in functions are *just unbeatable* for the operations they are designed for. This is especially true for `CountIf` and `CountIfs`. Forget about it.

You should not think about using something else, but probably about *when* to do the update. If the calculation of formulas is slowing down the editing of your worksheet, you might switch to *manual calculation*, which will permit you to trigger the calculation manually when needed.

You may also think of redesigning your data, or move it to a database in a way that exploits the indexing features that DBMS offers. Unfortunately, Excel with all its power, is not a DBMS.

Comment: Thank you!  I do have the data stored in a couple of SQL tables, but haven't been able to get the statements right, and since I'm far more comfortable in vba than in SQL, I was hoping to stick with it.  I'm afraid I may not have a choice but to learn something in SQL or deal with the lengthy processing time.
Appreciate your input!

Comment: @JP_Romano you're welcome. I believe DBMS/SQL is the way to go. Think of using the appropriate indexing to improve the search on the fields you're counting or searching.